# Яндек карты: получить список городов

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Мы не можем получить список городов. Даже если мы используем выборку Geocoder по kind: locality, то возвращаются и реки, и болота, и аэропорты и.т.п. Вопрос,

1. Как получить полный список городов?
2. Как получить список городов для конкретного региона (в том числе федерального центра)?

   ```
       ymaps.geocode(request.term, {
           kind: settings.kind
       }).then(
           function (res) {
               response($.yandexRegion.answerKind(res, value));
           },
           function (err) {
               // обработка ошибки
           }
       );
   ```

Comment: покажите запрос, который вы делаете сейчас

Comment: Обновил, посмотрите пж

Comment: Через геокодер нельзя получить полный список городов.